Remainder parse error in Django Template when using an if condition to check if age is greater than or equal to eighteen
Exception

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: >=18 from >=18

Code
{% for people in peoples %}
<tr>
  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
  <td>{{people.name}}</td>
  <td>{{people.age}}</td>
  <td {% if people.age >=18 %} style="backround:red" {% endif %}> #erro showing here
    {% if people.age >= 18 %}
    
    {% else %}
    
    {% endif %}
    
  </td>
</tr>


Django templates can nor render your template tag, simply add a space letter:
From this:
{% if people.age >=18 %}

to this:
{% if people.age >= 18 %}

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#id5
